# How do I control clipping in C# or XAML when using UniformToFill with an image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, clipping

I have an image control in a resizable window with its stretch property set to `UniformToFill`.

```
<Image Name="some_image" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

The clipping window is pegged to the top left of the image; resizing chops off the right and bottom of the image.

I want the image to be clipped equally on all sides. Am I being dense and overlooking an obvious solution?

How do I control how the image gets clipped?

(Unrelated: This is my first post to stackoverflow. I just wanted to start off saying, thanks, this site has been amazing resource for me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment property determine this behavior with an image control.

```
 <Image Name="some_image" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Guess i was being dense!

Comment: Thanks! Strangely enough I was also dense, and you posting this answwer has saved me a ton of work!

Comment: Just for the records - it will not work when the `Image` has `Width` and/or `Height` set. In this case put the `Image` inside a new `Grid` and set `Width` or `Height`, respectively, there.